# Is there a way to avoid error C2039: "value": Is not a member of "boost::proto"?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, vcpkg, cpp-netlib

I'm using `boost::network::uri::encoded()` to encode my request URL.
But when I'm building the project, I see the error:

```
error C2039: "value": Is not a member of "boost::proto"
```

There are four of them, and they're reported from:

```
boost\proto\generate.hpp(239,20);
boost\proto\generate.hpp(239,53);
boost\proto\generate.hpp(248,20);
boost\proto\generate.hpp(248,53)
```

This is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/network/uri.hpp"
using std::string;
string EncodeURL(string str)
{
    return boost::network::uri::encoded(str);
}
string DecodeURL(string str)
{
    return boost::network::uri::decoded(str);
}
int main()
{
    EncodeURL("https://test.com/a+a+a.html");
    return 0;
}
```

I installed `boost` and `cpp-netlib` using vcpkg. My IDE is Visual Studio Professional 2019, and the OS is Windows 10 Professional Workstation x64 (`Ver.2004`).
I want to know how to avoid those errors or another way to encode URLs that are UNICODE compatible.

Comment: BTW,there is no other errors reported.

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/boostorg/proto/issues/18 but it looks like it has been fixed in the development branch (not yet in a boost release)

Comment: Thank you for telling me that.May be consider write an answer,I will accept it.

Comment: It looks like it will be fixed in Boost 1.72

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug of boost library. It can be fixed by updating the boost library to the latest version or edit `boost\proto\generate.hpp`.

The way to edit `boost\proto\generate.hpp`:

Change line 95 to

```cpp
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, < 1800)
```

Change line 233 to

```cpp
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, < 1800)
```

This is the [PR](https://github.com/boostorg/proto/pull/19/commits/f7f698089b428b0139601cb8ff52a764eca16c7a) from boost libary.